# The frames' size automatically adjusts to widgets' size although propagate is set to false(0) in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, size, frame, root

This is my first experience with tkinter, and I am developing a program using it. To do so, I have an Application class that has all of my frames, buttons, entry boxes, etc. This class has methods like add_button, add_entry_box, etc. This is what my Application class's constructor looks like:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, texts, rows, cols, dimensions, bgs,
                 rowSpans, colSpans, stickyes, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
    
        self.frames = []
    
        b = 0
        for text in texts:
            bg = bgs[b]
            frame = tk.LabelFrame(text = text, bg = bg,
                                  width=dimensions[b][0],
                                  height=dimensions[b][1],
                                  padx=3, pady=3)
            frame.grid(padx=3, pady=3, column=cols[b], row=rows[b],
                       rowspan=rowSpans[b], columnspan=colSpans[b],
                       sticky=stickyes[b])
            frame.propagate(0)

            self.frames.append(frame)
            b += 1

        self.buttons = []
        self.entryBoxes = []
        self.labels = []
        self.textBoxes = []
        self.optionMenus = []
        self.figureCanvases = []
        self.topLevels = []
        self.checkButtons = []
```

And this is how the main program starts:

```
###Making the root###
root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('winnative')
root.configure(bg='#a9c2ed')
root.title('Something')
root.geometry('1150x750')
root.propagate(0)

frameTexts = ["Streamed video Section", "Control Panel", "Power Panel",
              "Angles' Display Section"] 
frameBackgroundColors = ['#a9c2ed', '#6b8aca', 'blue', '#4b6ab9',
                         '#B6E0F7']
frameRows = [0, 2, 3, 2]
frameCols = [0, 0, 1, 1]
frameRowSpans = [3, 2, 1, 1]
frameColSpans = [1, 1, 2, 2]
frameStickyes = [NW,"","",""]
frameDimensions = [[500,500], [300,300], [300,300], [250,250]]
#Dimensions --> [width, height]
myApp = Application(root, frameTexts, frameRows, frameCols,
                    frameDimensions, frameBackgroundColors,
                    rowSpans=frameRowSpans,
                    colSpans=frameColSpans,
                    stickyes=frameStickyes)
```

I have tried to fix the problem by setting propagate to zero, but as depicted in the image below, my frames (Power Panel for example) are automatically resized to the buttons' size:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7efU.png